# Big Commerce Prevent options showing which don't have SKU's

Tags: bigcommerce

I am developing an interface from our stock system into a Big Commerce based website, but I have hit a snag, which I am hoping someone can help with

We set up option sets …. Eg trousers, jackets etc
We then set up options trousers_size, trousers_colour, Jackets_size, jackets_colour  etc

Against each of our products we have the option set
So say we have 1 pair of trousers in sizes 30 and 32, colours Blue and black
We create 4 SKUS 30/blue, 32/blue, 30/black and 32/Black 
Then say we have another pair of trousers sizes 34 and 36 colours Red and green
Again in the same way we create 4 SKU’s, which all works fine

Now for the Issue!

When you view both products on the front end they have all sizes and all colours showing on both products, not just the ones with the SKU’s attached (I have previously interfaced into Magento and that only shows the relevant sizes/colours to that product ie ony the ones which have simples associated with them)

Is there any way to do this on Big Commerce? -- I am hoping that there is a switch somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up rules.

go to the product,

beneath the option for the SKU you can create Rules.

Select the colours and sizes that aren't available and then scroll down to the next set where it will say make this product unavailable- hide from store view (something along those lines) i know the basics ive written are correct but its a total nightmare if you have a lot to do. i cannot understand why they made it so complicated when all really need ideally are columns to import from with the sizes ,38,40,42 in one column and colour in another.. but noooo this is far better they say.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do it is through options. When you edit your options, you can specify which options should be displayed along with the product. [image: bc options screenshot][image: bc options screenshot]

Comment: This does not give a solution as some products in the option set will only be available in say Blue and Red, whereas some products in the same option group will only be available in Green and Yellow. The products will only have the relevant SKU's but when you view them on the front end the 2 different products will show all colours. I only want the front end to show options which are available in the SKU's attached to the product.

Comment: @AlanJones you can specify rules along with options. In the rules, you can disable the values from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to the change the store inventory setting to hide SKUs without stock.

To achieve this you:

1. From the left menu go to **Advanced Settings** › **Inventory**
2. Under *'General Settings'*, change *'When an option is out of stock'* to **Hide the option**

(You can do the same thing for products as a whole. This is not displayed in the image below)

[image]

Inventory setting documentation at:
https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Inventory-Settings